# Javascript generating html nesting in itself

Tags: javascript

so my code here:

```
function day(time) {
    jQuery.parseJSON(time);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://www.freecodecamp.com/news/hot", function(news) {
        var html = "";
        var br = "</br>";

        news.forEach(function(val) {
            html += "\n\
    <div class='col-md-3'>\n\
    <div class = 'panel panel-default'>\n     <div class = 'panel-image'> \n "
            html += "<img src='" + val.image + " 'width='100%' height='100%' />\n\
          </div>\n"

            html += "<a href='" + val.link + "'>" + val.headline + "</a></p>"
            html += "<p>by: <a href='http://www.freecodecamp.com/" + val.author.username + "'>" + val.author.username + "</a></p>"
            html += "<p> ♥" + " " + val.upVotes.length + "</p>"
            html += "<p>Posted on:" + day(val.timePosted)
            "</p>\n\
       </div>\n\
     </div>\n"

        });
        
        $(".stories").html(html);
      
    });
});
```

When it loops through the code it should be generating the individually but, the actual output of this function is generating the code as if its nesting everything in the col-md-3 div.

sort of like this:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="col-md-3'>
                .
                  .
                    .
                      <div...
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a `+` immediately after `+ day(val.timePosted)`. So you should have: `"<p>Posted on:" + day(val.timePosted) +  "</p>\n\ </div>\n\ </div>\n"`. Except keep your formatting :)

Comment: Also, your `day` function isn't returning anything. You probably want `return jQuery.parseJSON(time);`

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with your last string with the closing tags:

```js
html += "<p>Posted on:" + day(val.timePosted)
"</p>\n\
   </div>\n\
 </div>\n"
```

You need `html +=` before it, if you want to keep your current structure:

```js
html += "<p>Posted on:" + day(val.timePosted)
html += "</p>\n\
   </div>\n\
 </div>\n"
```

I recommend a tool like [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) or ESLint(http://eslint.org/) that can warn you about things like this. For example, pasting your code into JSHint's online linter shows

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

on the line in question.